# Javascript doesn't validate everything but only one Function

Tags: javascript, html, validation

How to make the validation for two functions.

Because i can go to the'success.html' after input the right info for the form (name,subject and number) but with the radiobuttons unchecked.

Iknow its something to do with the return function.

Just wondering if its possible to to have a function that validates another function?

```
<head>
<title>Exam Entry</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {
var result = true;
var msg="";

if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
msg+="You must enter your name \n";
document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
msg+="You must enter your subject \n";
document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value=="") {
msg+="You must enter the examnumber \n";
document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";
result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value.length!=4) {
msg+="You must enter at least Four Numbers in the ExamNumber \n";
document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";
result = false;
} 


var numbers = /^[0-9]{4}$/;


if (!(document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value.match(numbers))) {
    msg += "Only use numeric characters for the Examnumber \n";
    document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
    document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color = "red";
    result = false;
}  


if(msg==""){
return result;
}
{
alert(msg)
return result;
}
}


function confirmation() {

var checked = null;
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('examtype');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          if (inputs[i].checked) {
           checked = inputs[i];
   }
}
if(checked==null)
{
    alert('Please choose an exam level.');
    return false;
}
else{
     confirm('You have chosen '+checked.value+' is this correct?');
}

}




</script>
</head>


<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
<table width="50%" border="0">
<tr>
<td id="name">Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
<tr>
<td id="subject">Subject</td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="examnumber">Examination Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="examnumber" maxlength="4" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" id="examtype" name="examtype" value="GCSE" /> : GCSE<br />
<td><input type="radio" id="examtype" name="examtype" value="A2" /> : A2<br />
<td><input type="radio" id="examtype" name="examtype" value="AS"/> : AS<br />
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="confirmation();return validateForm

();"    />  </td>
<td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: you cannot have same id in multiple elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I move everything into one single function and messed about with the'return'

All done now! **IMPROVED CODE** test it for me and compare it

```
<head>
<title>Exam Entry</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function validateForm() {



var checked = null;
var inputs = document.getElementsByName('examtype');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          if (inputs[i].checked) {
           checked = inputs[i];
   }
}
if(checked==null)
{
    alert('Please choose an exam level.');
    return false;
}
else{
      confirm('You have chosen '+checked.value+' is this correct?');
}




var result = true;
var msg="";

if (document.ExamEntry.name.value=="") {
msg+="You must enter your name \n";
document.ExamEntry.name.focus();
document.getElementById('name').style.color="red";
result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.subject.value=="") {
msg+="You must enter your subject \n";
document.ExamEntry.subject.focus();
document.getElementById('subject').style.color="red";
result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value=="") {
msg+="You must enter the examnumber \n";
document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";
result = false;
}

if (document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value.length!=4) {
msg+="You must enter at least Four Numbers in the ExamNumber \n";
document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color="red";
result = false;
} 


var numbers = /^[0-9]{4}$/;


if (!(document.ExamEntry.examnumber.value.match(numbers))) {
    msg += "Only use numeric characters for the Examnumber \n";
    document.ExamEntry.examnumber.focus();
    document.getElementById('examnumber').style.color = "red";
    result = false;
}  




if(msg==""){
return result;
}
{
alert(msg)
return result;
}
}




</script>
</head>


<body>
<h1>Exam Entry Form</h1>
<form name="ExamEntry" method="post" action="success.html">
<table width="50%" border="0">
<tr>
<td id="name">Name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="name" /></td>
<tr>
<td id="subject">Subject</td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="examnumber">Examination Number</td>
<td><input type="text" name="examnumber" maxlength="4" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" id="examtype" name="examtype" value="GCSE" /> : GCSE<br />
<td><input type="radio" id="examtype" name="examtype" value="A2" /> : A2<br />
<td><input type="radio" id="examtype" name="examtype" value="AS"/> : AS<br />
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm();"/>  </td>
<td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Most importantly, add your validation function to your form.

```
<form
    name="myForm"
    method="post"
    action="foo.html"
    onsubmit="return validateForm()">
    ...
</form>
```

Other than that, simply call that one function inside the other and then handle the return value.

```
function validateForm() {

    result = true;

    //do some validation
    if(fails){
        //do some handling

        result = 0;
    }

    result = result && validateSpecial();

    return result;
}

function validateSpecial() {
    //check condition
    if(fails){
        //do stuff to handle failure

        result = 0;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: How would i do that then? You mean put a validate function within a function?

Comment: or can i just merge the two functions into one single validationform() { ??

Comment: of course you can, you can split or combine functions as needed — if your functions are only ever called on submit, you can sure combine them

Comment: Can u tell me how to combine the two function together with refrence to my code.

Comment: Okay i merged it in to one validateform() function but when i clicked submit only the radioboxes validation alert pops up. After i clicked on one of the radio buttons and click submit then the rest of the validation for the form works...

Comment: All done now! **IMPORVED CODE** test it for me and compare it ^^